# playwright force useragent for headless mode

Tags: python, playwright-python

How can I force the useragent in playwright python?

https://playwright.dev/python/docs/emulation#user-agent

```py
def run(playwright):
    """ config for browser """
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(channel='msedge', headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context(
        user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.81"
    )
    return browser


with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = run(p)
    # some info
    log.info(f"name:{browser.browser_type.name}, exe_path:{browser.browser_type.executable_path}, version:{browser.version}")
    page = browser.new_page()
    log.info(f"useragent:{page.evaluate('navigator.userAgent')}")
    page.goto(dat['url'])
    :
```

but useragent in headlessmode is always:
`useragent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/116.0.1938.81 Safari/537.36 HeadlessEdg/116.0.1938.81`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new_page()` needs to be called on the context you've created with the user agent, not the browser:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/116.0.1938.81"

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    context = browser.new_context(user_agent=ua)
    page = context.new_page()
    assert page.evaluate("navigator.userAgent") == ua
```

If you really want to use `run()`, you can:

```
def run(playwright):
    # ...
    return context, browser

with sync_playwright() as p:
    context, browser = run(p)
    page = context.new_page()
    # ...
```

Comment: This should be added to the documentation: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/emulation

Comment: Ah, I see where you got that code from. In their example, I don't think they're expecting you to return either the browser or context from `run()`. I think they expect you'll do all work requiring those variables inside `run()`, maybe returning a result at the end. That said, you certainly can return `browser` and `context` from `run()` if you want to--it's not a required pattern or anything.