# How to change the user-agent in playwright autotests

Tags: python, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, playwright-python

I can't run autotests using a headless browser, because my user agent = Headless Chrome. For this reason, I get to the page with the captcha=(. This is my current autotest code, please help me figure out how to add a user-agent

*helpers/web/pages/base.py*

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, page: Page):
        self.page = page
        self.base_url = BASE_URL
        self.user_agent = USER_AGENT
```

*helpers/web/pages/commands.py*

```
class Commands(Base):
    def navigate_to_main_page(self):
        self.page.goto(self.base_url)
```

*helpers/web/web.py*

```
class WEB:
    def __init__(self, page):
        self.command = Commands(page)
```

*tests/web/test_example.py*

```
class TestExample:

    def test_get_started_link(self, web):
            web.command.navigate_to_main_page()
```

Comment: See [playwright force useragent for headless mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77106304/playwright-force-useragent-for-headless-mode/77106405#77106405)